# routes as explained in RoR tutorial 2nd Ed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

The author, Michael Hartl, says:

> Here the rule:
>
> ```
> get "static_pages/home"
> ```
>
> maps requests for the URI /static_pages/home to the home action in the StaticPages controller.

How?  The type of request is given, the url is given, but where is the mapping to a controller and action?  My tests all pass, though.

I also tried deleting all the actions in the StaticPagesController, which just looks like this:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def about
  end

  def help
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

...and my tests still pass, which is puzzling.  No, I deleted all my actions like this:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
end
```

The 2nd edition of the book(online) is really frustrating.  Specifically, the section about making changes to the Guardfile is impossible to follow.  For instance, if I instruct you to edit this file:

```
blah blah blah
dog dog dog
beetle beetle beetle
jump jump jump
```

and make these changes:

```
blah blah blah
.
.
.
go go go
.
.
.
jump jump jump
```

...would you have any idea where the line 'go go go' should be in the code?

And the hint for exercise 3.5-1 is flat out wrong.  If the author would put up a comment section at the end of every chapter, the rails community could self-edit the book.

Tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do
  let(:base_title) { "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" }

  describe "Home page" do
    it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      visit "/static_pages/home"
      page.should have_selector(
            'title', 
            :text => "#{base_title} | Home")
    end

  end

  describe 'Help page' do
    it "should have the h1 'Help'" do
      visit "/static_pages/help"
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Help')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      visit '/static_pages/help'
      page.should have_selector(
            'title',
            :text => "#{base_title} | Help")
    end

  end

  describe 'About page' do
    it "should have the h1 'About'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'About')
    end

    it "should have the title 'About'" do
      visit '/static_pages/about' 
      page.should have_selector(
            'title',
            :text => "#{base_title} | About")
    end
  end

  describe 'Contact page' do
    it "should have the h1 'Contact'" do
      visit '/static_pages/contact'
      page.should have_selector('h1', :text => 'Contact')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
      visit '/static_pages/contact'
      page.should have_selector(
            'title', 
            :text => "#{base_title} | Contact")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: It seems that home action has't been deleted in your StaticPagesController yet. Try delete `def home end`.

Comment: If you have any complaints about the tutorial, I suggest you contact the author directly as it will greatly help him improve the tutes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to this conundrum.  First of all, this is a rails 'problem' not an rspec problem; if I add a route to routes.rb such as:

```
get "static_pages/dog"
```

...and then enter the url

```
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/dog
```

in my browser, rails complains:

> Unknown action
>
> The action 'dog' could not be found for StaticPagesController

Then if I add the dog action to the controller, then create a view,
everything works fine and dandy.

But if I then delete the dog action, and then use the same url,

```
http://localhost:3000/static_pages/dog
```

in my browser, this time I get a different result--instead of getting an error the view displays.

As it turns out, that inconsistent behavior is a rails 'feature' called default rendering, explained here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action

According to the docs, all that's needed to render a page is a route and a view--the action is optional.

Comment: that's what i meant in my comments but at least you found it out yourself too :)

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints

it is just a shorthand for

```
match 'static_pages/home' => 'static_pages#home', :via => :get
```

Basically Rails infers from your url `static_pages/home` that you are referring to the StaticPagesController's home action.

Also, when you 'deleted' all your actions, you left the action definitions - which is what the test checks. It just checks if it can go to the home action of your staticpages controller. It doesn't matter if it does nothing, as long as it exists(at least that's what I think your tests does - care to post the tests also?)

If you delete

```
...
def home
end
...
```

from your controller, I'm pretty sure your tests will fail

Comment: No.  I deleted all the actions like this--can't figure out how to add code, so I added it to my op.  A simple explanation of the shortcut would have been helpful.  Actually, not using a shortcut for the first route would be even more helpful.

Comment: If you can post your tests as well it would help to see why they still pass

Comment: I added the tests to my op.  I'm using guard/spork, and I restarted guard/spork and everything still passes.  From the comments, it sounds like the tests shouldn't pass, which is what puzzled me--because I don't think the tests should pass either.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but if I change 'h1' to 'h2', a test will fail--as it should.

Comment: for some reason, it seems like your controllers aren't being reloaded. The best way to check this is to kill guard, spork and then grep if there are any ruby processes running `ps -ef | grep ruby` and kill those as well. For good measure, quit your terminal and then try running your tests again(without guard or spork this time) - you do know how to right?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already tried all that (except for ps). I even shut down my computer. I can manually run the tests using $rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb and the same thing happens--all the tests pass even though there are no actions in the StaticPagesController. So I did an rm -rf on my sample_app directory, and I started over. This time before I even got to the guard/spork installation section, the tests pass after I delete all the actions. I'm trying to pinpoint at what stage the actions become irrelevant for passing the tests.

Comment: All I know is when I added the test for the non-existent 'About page', I got three errors: 1) No matching route, then after I added the route, 2) No matching action, then after I added the action, 3) No view. So at that point the actions were required to pass the tests. Somewhere after that the actions become superfluous. Does it have anything to do with adding the provide() method in the views? By the way any tests, views, controllers, etc. can be examined on the book's website. Thanks. Oh, yeah, here is the result of ps -ef | grep ruby 501 918 878 0 0:00.00 ttys000 0:00.00 grep ruby

Comment: Here is my info: ~/rails_projects/sample_app25$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
~/rails_projects/sample_app25$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.8

Comment: I tried adding a test for a non-existent page, and I got the same three errors as mentioned in my previous comment.  After adding the route, action, and view to get the test to pass, I deleted all the actions in the StaticPagesController, and once again all the tests passed. That leads me to believe that rspec is NOT running tests that have previously passed. I don't know how to fix that, but that seems to be what is happening. To run the tests, I'm doing: ~/rails_projects/sample_app25$ rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb

Comment: rspec version: ~/rails_projects/sample_app25$ rspec -v
2.10.1

Comment: So you mean to say adding a new static page makes it fail, but once it passes, even if you try to delete it, it doesn't fail anymore? That IS weird. do you have a git repo where I can check it out? I'd like to see your code itself(not the one from the book)

Comment: I don't think my previous conclusion was correct.  If I change a test to look for an h2 tag in the view instead of an h1 tag(there are no h2 tags in the view), then the test will fail.  So rspec is still running all the tests that previously passed.  However if I delete the corresponding action, i.e. the one specified in the test: visit 'static_pages/non_exist' in the StaticPagesController, then the test still passes.  So rspec is not paying any attention to the StaticPagesController once a test passes.  I'll push everything up to github and post the link.

Comment: I've checked it out and it looks I have yet to answer you more fully on this. For some magical reason, Rails uses AbstractController to cover for you if you don't have a controller defined(try renaming staticpagescontroller and running your tests again). Basically, as long as you have a view with the same name and path as your route, you'll get that static page as if it passed through your controller. BUT only for static pages. if you need variables you're definitely going to use controllers and your tests will definitely fail. Read on, maybe it is explained in the rest of the chapters :)

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. If I change the name of the class StaticPagesController, all the tests fail. I get a LoadError:  
       Expected /Users/7stud/rails_projects/sample_app25/app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb to define StaticPagesController.  And if I change the name of the file static_pages_controller.rb, all the tests fail.

Comment: By the way, I altered a view to this: <h1><%= @x %>Non</h1>, and there is no action in the controller for that view, so @x is not being set--and the tests all pass.